# Are subdomains considered "websites" in Django sites framework?

Tags: django, django-sites, django-subdomains

I am developing a language-based web application using Django.

I would like to separate content using language subdomains (similar to Wikipedia, Quora, and other multilingual websites). For example, if my website were **website.com**, I would like to have **en.website.com** for the English version of my website, **es.website.com** for the Spanish version of my website, and so on and so forth.

To achieve this, I was considering using [the "sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/) from Django, but its documentation is not very explicit about subdomains. Rather, it talks about "websites" and "sites," and it's not clear whether the framework would be suitable for my purpose.

So, my question is this: According to the documentation's terminology, can you treat subdomains as "websites" in the Django sites framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, yes you can.

You may also want to look into e.g. https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for subdomain-based routing.

Comment: If you are familiar with these technologies, what are the differences between the two, and which one would you recommend for subdomains specifically? Thank you, @AKX